# Como trabalhar com tipo generico

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Olá! Estou começando no Delphi e estava criando um método para adicionar *margin* a um objeto, mas precisava que fosse para qualquer objeto.
Exemplo do código no qual estava trabalhando.

---

Abaixo o exemplo do código que eu fiz para criar a *margin*

```
procedure EditRectangleMargin(rtObjeto : TRectangle; bottom : double; left : double; right : double; top : double);
Begin
  //Seta a Magin do Objeto
   rtObjeto.Margins.Bottom := bottom;
   rtObjeto.Margins.Left := left;
   rtObjeto.Margins.Right := right;
   rtObjeto.Margins.Top := top;
```

---

Mas gostaria de fazer um método genérico que atendesse tanto *rectangle* quando *layout*, *label* etc.
Tem como criar algo assim em Delphi?

OBS: estou utilizando o firemonkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A propriedade Margins vem do TControl, por isso pode alterar a sua funçao para receber um TControl em vez de um TRectangle.

```
procedure EditRectangleMargin(rtObjeto : TControl...
```

Já que o TLayout, TLabel, TRectangle e muitos outros descendem do TControl. Assim pode enviar todos os controlos que descreveu usando apenas uma função.

Comment: Mas como eu implemento isso, digo, tenho que importar algo? pois só aparece o TControlSize, mas este não tem as propriedades;

Comment: Não tem de importar nada, o TControl existe de certeza :p Se alterar o header da sua funçao para isto:

procedure EditRectangleMargin(rtObjeto : TControl; bottom : double; left : double; right : double; top : double);

Dá algum erro no compilador?

Comment: Deu certo,  é que como estava utilizando uma Unit sem Form então precisei importar o FMX.Controls;
Vlw cara.

Comment: Ah ok ;) De nada